# Can arcserver be used to populate jquery autocomplete?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, jquery, arcgis-server

I would like to set up autocomplete on a text box using jquery autocomplete with data from an arcserver service.  I'm wondering if this is possible and if so how i would implement it.  I'm using the esri javascript api v3.3 and arcserver 10.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, you are just passing an array to the autocomplete widget. If the data is in a map or feature service, query for the data from the service. If you start with a table in your mxd/msd that contains the data, when you publish it, you will get a REST endpoint for the table to query for in the same way. Next, parse out the data and push onto an array and pass it to the autocomplete widget.

```
    //build query task
    var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3");
    //create an array
    var aStateNames = [];

    //build query filter
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.returnGeometry = false;
    query.outFields = ["STATE_NAME"];
    query.where = "OBJECTID > 0";
    queryTask.execute(query, function (results) {
        //parse results and add to autocomplete widget
        dojo.forEach(results.features, function(value, index){
             aStateNames.push(value.attributes.STATE_NAME);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        alert("Error: " + error);
    });
```

Comment: Excellent, that works exactly as i wanted.  Thanks.